# JQuery - Trying to look at the change from one input to another input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one input that's value is a SUM of a bunch of select options. From there I am setting up another input that looks at the value from the first input and is suppose to update when the first one changes (plan to do more with it, but can't get past this step). Unfortunately the second is not updating on change.

Sample HTML:

```
<select name="product-attr-os">
    <option data-selected="house" value="10">Made in House</option>
    <option data-selected="license" value="
            15">Licensed Software</option>
    <option data-selected="open" value="20">Open Source</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="product-attr-network">
    <option data-selected="3g" value="40">3G</option>
    <option data-selected="4g" value="
                45">4G/LTE</option>
    <option data-selected="5g" value="50">5G</option>
</select>
<p>Attr Total Cost</p>
<input type="text" class="product-attr-totalCost" name="product-attr-totalCost" readonly />
<p>Standard Cost</p>
<input type="text" class="product-standardCost" name="product-standardCost" readonly />
```

JQuery:

```
// SUM (Product Attributes)
var productAttrTotal = function (inputs, output, selected) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(inputs).bind('change', function () {

            var sum = 0;
            $(inputs).find(selected).each(function () {
                sum += parseInt($(this).val());
            });

            $(output).val(sum);

        });
        $(inputs).trigger('change');
    });
};

productAttrTotal('select', '.product-attr-totalCost', ':selected');


// Product Attributes Total + Wifi
var productTotalCost = function (attrCost, totalCost) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(attrCost).bind('change', function () {
            $(totalCost).val($(attrCost).val());
        });
        $(attrCost).trigger('change');
    });
};

productTotalCost('.product-attr-totalCost', '.product-standardCost');
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/geqvn/6/)

Comment: do you want the same price in both the fields

Comment: Yes I do for now. I am going to add something to the second function "productTotalCost" that increases the price but I need to make sure it at least meets this requirement first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display same value in both the input fields, pass the selector for both of them as the output using multiple selector

```
productAttrTotal('select', '.product-attr-totalCost, .product-standardCost', ':selected');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/83Rkg/)

Also note to trigger the change event on page load for only one of the select element

```
$(inputs).first().trigger('change');
```

---

In that case

```
productAttrTotal('select', '.product-attr-totalCost', ':selected');
```

then once the value of update is changed using script trigger the change event

```
$(inputs).first().trigger('change');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AkKQw/)

Comment: Sorry there was something I was not clear on. I want the second input to take the value of the first. Next I'm going to add additional code to the second function that will allow me to increase it by an additional value. My first goal is to make sure they mimic.